# Processing local variable with regular expressions

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, fish

I have some video files in `source/` to encode and I want the output to be saved in the local directory, therefore removing `source/` in the filename.

I accomplished this by using the following command in fish shell:

```
$ for file in source/*.mkv
      ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:v copy -c:a copy (echo "$file" | sed -e "s/source\///")
  end
```

Although, I find piping the output of `echo` to `sed` a bit rudimentary, is there a function that just processes the strings of local variables? Like a `sed` but just for local variables or filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing a (fixed) directory name from the string here.

In standard shell, you can do that with the `${parameter#pattern}` [expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073), it removes `pattern` from the start of the string in `parameter`, so `${file#source/}` would remove the prefix `source/`.

Also in ksh/Bash/zsh `${parameter/pattern}` removes the match anywhere in the string, which matches sed's `s/pattern//` more closely. (`${..//..}` to remove all matches). Those [patterns are the same as the ones used for filename wildcards](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns); they're not regexes.

---

In `fish`, there's the [builtin `string replace` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string), which seems it can be used here:

```
> set f source/foobar
> string replace source/ "" -- $f
foobar
```

or with `-r` for regex, so we don't need to know the path:

```
> string replace -r "^.*/" "" -- $f
foobar
```

(Note that I'm not that familiar with fish. The above seemed to work, but I'm not sure if it breaks in some corner cases.)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `basename`:

```
ffmpeg -i $file -c:v copy -c:a copy (basename $file)
```